# Border for link with type "submit" isn't disappearing in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

all.  I've spent a few hours on what should be very simple before figuring out that chrome was my problem.  Essentially, I'm trying to format a link of type "submit" such that it no longer looks like a button.  My CSS is:

```css
a[type="submit"]:link,
a[type="submit"]:focus,
a[type="submit"]:visited,
a[type="submit"]:active {
  background: #fff;
  border: 0 !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none!important;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" name="set" type="submit" value="set">Text</a>
```

Weirdly, it looks fine in this code snippet.  However, when I run this in my project, chrome does not remove the border around the link that appears when I set the type to "submit".  It does successfully change the background color to white.  Things look fine when opened in firefox.  Is there any way to get around this in chrome?

Comment: `when I run this in my project` < this part is the most important unless you specify more context is difficult to help without understanding the cause of the issue. My guess is that there is some other rule overriding the ones you have defined here. Go into devtools and check the computed styles.

Comment: What looks to you as a border might actually be obtained using a different property, a pseudo-element or a dynamically added element altogether. Without the ability to inspect it, there's no way to tell. The way to go about this is inspecting an example displaying the behavior, figuring out what styles apply and where they come from. Without a [mcve], we can't help.

Comment: Attribute `type` on an `<a>` tag expects a Mime Type for the linked URL. Why are you setting it to `submit`?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be getting confused between an [anchor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) and a [button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)

`:visited` and `:link` are CSS pseudo-classes usually used for styling an anchor element.

`type="submit"` is for a button element. And while `type` *can* be set on an anchor element, it will only...

> specify the media type in the form of a MIME type for the linked URL. It is purely advisory, with no built-in functionality.

```css
button[type="submit"],
button[type="submit"]:focus,
button[type="submit"]:active {
  background: #fff;
  border: 0 !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none!important;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<button name="set" type="submit" value="set">Text</button>
```